# SMH not working on Proliant - how to use HPSUM?

Tags: hp-proliant

Need help from a Proliant professional. On my ML150 Gen9 I run Windows Server 2012 R2 with Hyper-V role. It's a single server environment (SMB), the OS is  installed as core system. System Management Homepage (SMH) does not show any item, neither any data source to select (usually SNMP or WBEM). I already ran latest version of SPP. I did this way: Mounting the ISO on a seperate management PC, launching HPSUM GUI and executing remote node deployment. But obviously it did not install all necessary modules.

Trying to find out what's going on I'm lost in the HP chaos of different options (SNMP, WBEM, AMS), dead document links and missing setup guides. What I want to achieve is to use SMH and, additionally, have an alerting of hardware failures. As far as I see the way to achieve this with least impact on OS is to use ILO/AMS (Agentless Management Service) for alerting and WBEM for SMH. So my questions are:

1) How to find out what is missing?

2) How to add needed and delete unneeded modules (probably SNMP), since there seems to be no way to provide or delete single items with HPSUM?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just run the SPP locally on the server via iLO to make sure the BIOS/firmware is up to date then again via the OS? If you run it in interactive mode you get to choose what to install or ignore - I choose to ignore those that need SNMP setting up first.

Comment: Thanks for comment. There is no browser on this core system, so I cannot run HPSUM GUI via iLO or OS. BIOS and drivers are up to date, I checked that in deployment report.